# I am stuck out of my host server ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ovh

I have a dedicated server and I wanted to login to ssh and I changed the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file but then I could not login my ssh of server. When I run this command I get;

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "akillisaha.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to akillisaha.com [5.135.141.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to akillisaha.com:22 as 'ahmetb'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4113/8192
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:+BLBEx4qLkEES1Ull8bhGEXMHIfJ0n1n8oty66H0jPw
debug1: Host 'akillisaha.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/selcuk/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug2: bits set: 4150/8192
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55f67f484260), agent
debug2: key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/selcuk/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I have to login to my ssh and change the config file. But tha's not possible. Please help me . . ..

Comment: You say you need to login via SSH, but you've broken SSH.  Do you mean to say that SSH is the only option?  i.e., is the server remote and not physically accessible?  What kind of hardware are you running on?  Or is it a virtual machine?  More detail is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

The server did not accept the ssh key your computer presented, and the server is configured to refuse password logins via ssh.

To find out why the server didn't accept the key, requires inspecting the *server* logs.

To regain access to your server, you must use the IPMI console provided by the dedicated server provider. You can then log in and resolve the problem.

[image: OVH dedicated server screenshot]